# the use of ajax jquery I want a message that does not expect an Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In one form an ajax call and at the end of it ok sending a message without waiting for a response from it; the code used is:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST", url: "page.aspx",
 data: { "one": "one", "two": "two", ...},
 datatype: "html", })

swal({ title: '', text: 'OK', type: 'success'})
```

but it happens that after a while time the message disappears,
no one click on the button ....
I do not know how to make sure that the message always appears and then goes away to click on the button! I ask for help ...

Comment: What's `swal` (ie, include the details in the question)

Comment: What happens if you take out the `$.ajax` call?   Seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: You'll need to create a [mcve] - it's highly likely there's some *other* code causing it to go (eg a form post as mentioned by @Desperado)

Comment: There appear to be a number of forks of `swal` - without knowing which one is being used, it's possible (though unlikely) the fork in use has a default timeout - just guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous, it will not halt execution.
Put your swal after the ajax finished executing.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST", url: "page.aspx",
 data: { "one": "one", "two": "two", ...},
 datatype: "html", 
 beforeSend: function(){
   swal({ title: '', text: 'OK', type: 'success'})
 }
})
```

If disappearing of swal is an issue, then this might be a possible cause
You have a submit call that closes the swal. Cannot verify though need to see complete code.

Comment: ok, but so it will wait for the called procedure, but I want the message immediately ..

Comment: The issue, as described in the question, is not that the `swal` is called too soon, but that it disappears after some time.

Comment: @freedomn-m the swal will not disappear look on their documentation page, unless you explicitly set it. http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Comment: @Dave replace `success` with `beforeSend` to call it before processing the ajax request

Comment: @Desperado why are you telling *me* this?  I'm just providing information from the question, which states: "*but it happens that after a while time the message disappears*".

Comment: @freedomn-m for your reference only on what is the normal behavior of swal, not to spark an argument

Comment: the problem is that you update the page, and to refresh it (so to return the call page) the page will reload and the message will disappear ... help

Comment: If you could provide the complete code, if not complete just an overview of the process so we can pin-point issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

The problem was that I called another page. Here it was probably the calling page and reload in case insert after ajax education the "return false", was not "call".

I posted it all in a function of the calling page in a WebMethod function, which calls it by ajax and them in the option that you have shown me (beforeSend) send the message.

I thank you a thousand times.